# How to write a selector like this: $('.classname.active') if '.classname' is stored in a $var?

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables, css-selectors, traversal

I want to store a selector in a variable and I want to use that object in instances where I need to find a class of '.active'. Which would return the object that is '.active'.

Basically, how would i write a selector like this: $('.classname.active')

```
var $varName = $('.multipleDivs');
$varName.hasClass('active'); // this returns true, but not the object

var $varName = $('.multipleDivs'); 
$('.active', $varName); // this returns an empty array
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your original guess is the right way to do it.

```
$(".multipleDivs.active")
```

alternatively, you can do

```
$varName.filter(".active")
```

Answer (score 2):

`.hasClass()` returns boolean by design - it tests if an element has the named class. To filter down, you want either `.filter()` (if '.multipleDivs' also have the class '.active) or `.find()` (if the '.active' elements are children of the '.multipleDivs').

Answer (score 2):

```
var $varName = $('.multipleDivs');
$varName.hasClass('active'); // this returns true, but not the object
```

You are checking here whether any of div with class multipleDivs has class active

```
var $varName = $('.multipleDivs'); 
$('.active', $varName); // this returns an empty array
```

Here you are looking for elements with active class that are children of multipleDivs class elements.

Comment: The difference between this method and `$.filter` is that this doesn't change the original object containing all the `.multipleDivs`.

Answer (score 1):

The following should do it and use the syntax you mentioned

```
var clsName = 'multipleDivs';
var elementsWithBothClasses = $('.' + clsName + '.active');
```

If you already have the  jQuery object with all the `multipleDivs`, then, you may use `$.filter`

```
var multipleDivs = $('.multipleDivs');
multipleDivs.filter(".active"); // filters in place, so it changed multipleDivs
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var someRandomClass = "bill";
var results = $('.' + someRandomClass + '.active');
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/gromer/fSrAY/

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way to do do it:

```
var $varName = $('.multipleDivs');
$varName.each(function(){
  if($varName.hasClass('active');){
    $varName.whateverFunctionYouWantToDo();
  }
});
```